# How to measure the hop counts between two ips?

Tags: networking, ip

I want to measure the hop-counts between my target host and any other host. The target host is certain and other hosts are randomly selected. Both of them can not be controlled by me. How can i do it? In other words, I want to measure two hosts' hop counts which I cannot operate on.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Trace route is probably what you're interested in.

Comment: The way I'm reading this, I don't think Traceroute will help. Wanying Gong is at machine A, his target is machine B, and the "other host" is machine C. Traceroute can tell them the hops between A and B, or between A and C. But not the hops between B and C.

Comment: @DougDeden You are right. It puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reluctant to answer with a blanket statement like "You can't do that." Because it's so hard to prove a negative. But if you don't have access to either of the other hosts, you can't be certain of the path between them.

You say "both of them can not be controlled by me". You don't need to "control" them -- you just need to be able to run a program on them. But you go on to say they are hosts "which I cannot operate on". That sounds like you can't get enough access to them to even run a program like traceroute.

The best I can come up with is that you could run a traceroute from your machine to each of the hosts, and then look to see if there are any hops in common. That wouldn't guarantee anything, but it would at least provide you with a *potential* route between the two remote hosts.

For example, if I run a traceroute to www.example.**com**, it might start at my local gateway, then hit my ISP's router (all it AT&T), then AT&T in the center of my city, then AT&T's router in Chicago, then AT&T's router in Detroit, then a router belonging to Example.**com**'s ISP (call it Century Link) in Detroit, then Century Link's router at Example.com's Detroit data center, then Example.com's router, then the www.example.**com** machine.

Similarly, if I run a traceroute to www.example.**net**, it might start at my local gateway, then hit AT&T's router, then AT&T in the center of my city, then my AT&T's router in Chicago, then AT&T's router in Dallas, then a router belonging to Example.**net**'s ISP (call it Sprint) in Dallas, then Sprint's router at Example.net's Dallas data center, then Example.net's router, then the www.example.**net** machine.

So, a likely route from www.example.**com** to www.example.**net** could start at Example.com's Detroit data center, hop on Century Link from that data center to Detroit to Chicago to Dallas and then to a Sprint router in Dallas, and then then Sprint's router at Example.net's Dallas data center, then Example.net's router, then the www.example.**net** machine. And Sprint might have a direct route from Detroit to Dallas, saving a hop.

Again, this doesn't mean that's the path such traffic would take, but it gives you a likely upper bound.

If you are just interested in the counts, and not the specific route taken, the best you can do is assert that the hop count from B to C should never be greater than (the hop count from A to B) plus (the hop count from A to C). And it will almost certainly be at least one fewer, because it should not have to get all the way to A before turning around and heading for C. (Although routes can vary as machines come and go, so that further complicates things.)

If you can provide a bit more information about why you want to do this, we might be able to provide other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I want to draw a network topology map of some hosts.